# Delta time not working correctly in game engine - LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a simple game engine and I'm trying to make delta time available to the user. This is how it is calculated and given to the user (they get it as a float):

```
float deltaTime;
long lastLoop = System.nanoTime();
UpdateInfo updateInfo = new UpdateInfo(0, 0, gameInstance.window.getWindowHandle());

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gameInstance.window.getWindowHandle()))
{
    deltaTime = (float)((System.nanoTime() - lastLoop) / 1000000f);
    updateInfo.setDeltaTime(deltaTime);

    if (gameInstance.window.isFPSCounterEnabled())
    {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFrameCount >= 1000)
        {
            fps = frames;
            frames = 0;
            lastFrameCount = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fps = -1;
    }

    updateInfo.setFPS(fps);
    gameInstance.updateGame(updateInfo);
    gameInstance.drawGame(gameInstance.window.getDrawboard());
    lastLoop = System.nanoTime();
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

But when I test the delta time value in moving a sprite across the screen, it's really choppy. This is both when VSync is enabled and disabled. Am I calculating it wrong or is my game being unstable?

Comment: Can you define choppy? How does the data arrange itself (randomly, increases and then a sudden massive decrease, etc)?  For delta time, one thing I see is that the lastLoop variable should be set immediately after delta time is set, rather than after all the logic has executed.

Comment: I thought delta time was supposed to be the measured time between drawing/rendering?

Comment: That is correct, but you have it measuring just `glfwPollEvents()`